# How to limit character repetition in a word to 2?

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to remove characters that repeat more than twice in a word. For example

```
 "hhaaappppyyyyyyy mmoooooorning friendsssssssssssssss, good goood day"
```

to

```
 "hhaappyy mmoorning friendss, good good day"
```

I have tried something like this, but it is not reducing to exactly 2 repetitions.

```
gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1{2}', '\\1', 
   'hhaaappppyyyyyyy mmoooooorning friendsssssssssssssss, good goood day')

#[1] "hhappyyy mmoorning friendsssss, good god day"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `{2,}` quantifier and use two `\1` in the replacement:

```
s<-'hhaaappppyyyyyyy mmoooooorning friendsssssssssssssss, good goood day'
gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1{2,}', '\\1\\1', s)
# => [1] "hhaappyy mmoorning friendss, good good day"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/jqihYe).

The `([[:alpha:]])\\1{2,}` pattern matches and captures a letter into Group 1 and then 2 or more repetitions of the same char are matched. Two `\1` in the replacement pattern replace the whole match with 2  occurrences of the char. It is valid to use two `\1` placeholders because every match is at least 3 identical chars.

Answer (score 1):

Same as from Wiktor Stribiżew, but in javascript and replace **every** character (numbers, punctuation also), if you need this.

```js
var sInput = "hhaaappppyyyyyyy mmoooooorning friendsssssssssssssss, good goood day";
var sOutput = sInput.replace(/(.)\1{2,}/g, "$1$1");
console.log(sOutput);
```

Comment: It was tagged `r` for a reason, I guess :)

Comment: Thanks.It may help to people who are looking for the same functionality in java.

Answer (score 1):

fwiw, here is another solution:

```
f = function(x){
    x = strsplit(x, '')[[1]]
    x = rle(x)
    x = rep(x$values, pmin(2, x$lengths))
    paste(x, collapse='')
}
```

example:

```
x = "hhaaappppyyyyyyy mmoooooorning friendsssssssssssssss, good goood day"
f(x)
[1] "hhaappyy mmoorning friendss, good good day"
```

however, gsub is a little easier...

Answer (score 0):

package test.com;

public class limitCharCount {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String str = "gggkjjkjkjjjjjsssslklkkkkkk";

    char ch[] = str.toCharArray();
    String Test = "";
    //int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i == 0 ||i == 1)
            Test = Test + ch[i];
        else if (!(ch[i]==ch[i-1] && ch[i]==ch[i-2]) )
        {
            Test = Test + ch[i];
        }

    }
```

System.out.println(Test);
}

}
output ::ggkjjkjkjjsslklkk

Comment: Consider [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69646904/edit) and providing a description on how your code addresses the problem.